# Fullscreen an image placed in a button in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

Now i'm creating a quiz which has answers are images. I put each of them in an button to trigger my own event. The problem i having now is when I hold the button,the image in it will be fullscreen and when I don't hold it,the image return back. I have tried stretch property of image but it doesn't take effect.Please help me to find out the solution. Thanks. Here is my code:

```
<Button Name="Answer0Button" Hold="Answer0Button_OnHold"  Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="{Binding Markers, Converter={StaticResource markersConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Answers[0],Converter={StaticResource quizImagePathConverter}}"/>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding AssertCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Answers[0]}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Button>
```

When I debug, this button doesn't get the event on hold.

```
private void Answer0Button_OnHold(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        //Make the image fullscreen here
    }
```

Comment: Add the c# code also , to Know Your problem completely

Comment: I still don't have any idea to solve the problem. So i don't have any c# code, but what I want is with <Button Hold="<event>">, It will make the image inside the button zoom fullscreen. Please help me.

Comment: so no one could help me?..:(

Comment: can you please show more of your xaml. Your button is limited in width/height somehow, but that is not shown here.

Comment: hi Shawn Kendrot, imagine I have a quiz with 4 answers are pictures. My goal now is when I hold the button above,the pic answer will be zoom out fit to full screen and till now I don't have any idea to solve this problem, could you help me pls?